# Razor.RuntimeCompilation creates an error

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, runtime, razor-pages

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oD95.png)

I added the `AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` package for live updating of `.cshtml` pages.

But when writing

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

an error occurs in the `Program.cs` file:

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. When compiled with the usual builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(), everything works correctly.

The package version is correct and no other errors occur. Please tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Have you added `IHttpContextAccessor` dependency within your program.cs file? Because the error indicates, you are not accessing that accordingly.  Please Share more details along with reproducuble sample.